# Verify this identity

Tags: trigonometry

I need to verify this identity but I have no clue how to solve it. I have tried many different ways but haven't been able to figure it out. 
$$\frac{\cos^2(t)+\tan^2(t)-1}{\sin^2(t)}=\tan^2(t).$$

Comment: It is not clear what the expression is.

Comment: The way it's currently written is not an identity.  $cos^2(t)-1/sin^2(t)=0 \implies cos^2(t)=1/sin^2(t) \implies cos^2(t)=csc^2(t)$ But this isn't true for all $t$. Can you recheck the expression?

Comment: @Brittany: I have rewritten your expression to what I hope you intended. Please correct me if I am wrong.  Perhaps you meant to write $(\cos^2 t+\tan^2 t-1)/\sin^2 t$ and left out the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\cos^2(t)+\tan^2(t)-1}{\sin^2(t)}=\dfrac{\tan^2(t)-\sin^2(t)}{\sin^2(t)}=\dfrac{\tan^2(t)}{\sin^2(t)}-1=\sec^2(t)-1=\tan^2(t).$$